# mapfile validation

Tags: mapserver, mapfile

I'm looking for something that will do validation of a mapfile.  Some googling for the terms `mapfile` `validation` isn't coming up with hints of such a utility.

Is there anything that will verify mapfile formatting is correct?

Comment: In QGIS you can export the qgs file Info a mapfile. Then you can adapt the file to you needs.

Comment: Unfortunately we have a very large mapfile that is already built.  Everytime someone edits the thing I worry that it hasn't been formatted correctly.  

That said, I didn't know you could do that with qgis. Learned something new.

Comment: Also interested in the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I found one utility which can be used to open and edit the .map file. I think you can use that, maybe it may resolve your problem.

You can [download](https://web.archive.org/web/20170627030143/http://gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1600-gdal-2-1-mapserver-7-0/MapManager.msi) MapServer MapManager from [here](https://www.gisinternals.com/mapmanager.html).

Answer (score 0):

Update: I used strace to see what the fcgi does when it crashes, and it looks like it happens while it reads the qgs file. So maybe the problem is simply that there is missing info there? Maybe OWS server params?